# Java Selenium webdriver : How to handle authentication window post login

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a login scenario for a web app , where after submitting username and password we see a native authentication pop-up(Not HTML) .

Scenario

```
sendKeys("Email","Test");
sendKeys("Password","user");
click('Login');
```

Post clicking on Login , we see a authentication window in which we have to enter different credentials

Problem : After clicking on login button ,control never goes to next Line and it throws timeout exception(closing out the authentication pop up) . Any suggestions how to handle this .

What all i've tried so far - alert.authenticateUsing() and robot Script are not useful yet because control never goes to next line .

username:password@url is not an option because that url be generated after first credentials are validated.

ENV : MAC , Selenium 3.3 , Chrome Latest

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it with username:password@url using some internal hacks